# Interlacing for images

Tags: html, image, jpeg, interlacing

I'm creating a website for my photography business and I've encounter a problem. The images in the website are not loading quickly enough, and the page stays blank while these images are loading. I've already tried reducing the size of the images and it still doesn't work.

I've been told that a very good way is to use interlacing, but I've tried to do some research on how to apply it and it's like there are not answers in Google for this question, so it would be really helpful if you could tell me how to apply this to my webpage.

I'm including the link to my website in here, in case you want to check the loading problem I'm talking about. https://serchpics.github.io/Homepage/index.html :)

Comment: "I've been told that a very good way is to use interlacing" - err.... while this is technically true, this is very old advice (dating back to the 1990s). A better solution is just to compress your images better. I took a look at your github.io page and I see that each of your images are sized over 2MB, that's completely unnecesssary: a photographic JPEG or WebP image for typical web-page use shouldn't be more than a few hundred KB at most.

Comment: Depending on the size of the image file you would probably be better off simply reducing the image filesize rather than interlacing the visible file. There are a number of programs that can help cut excess file size from images without any visual loss of quality.

Comment: Yes, [your images](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/93047145/158072838-5ae57ed6-ec2f-4d1d-a950-6f3695cab2ea.jpg) are far too big dimensionally; you really don't need a 6000px wide image for your website. You can easily resize this image down to 2000px at most and slightly increase its compression (JPEG compression is not noticible until 75%) so rather than 0% compressed you can 25% compress the JPEG image and bang it can load in 150kb.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to reduce size of Large(ish) image for web page download](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4504497/how-to-reduce-size-of-largeish-image-for-web-page-download)

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4504497/how-to-reduce-size-of-largeish-image-for-web-page-download) are some ideas for you to explore

Comment: Okay thx, I'll try to compress them to a couple hundred kilobytes